# Dharma ransomeware files decryption

Tags: decryption, ransomware

One of my clients send me some picture that shows they infected by some ransomware. As i analysed i found that ransomware is probably Dharma ransomware, child of Crysis. so i tried to decrypt files with Kaspersky and avast tools but failed. 
Files renamed to some thing like :

```
test1.txt.id-XXX.[black.mirror@qq.com].java
```

The real file name was `test1.text`

[image: I attacked ransomware screen]. I need a tool to decrypt them for a decryption with master key for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware/ransomware removal forum.

Answer (score 2):

NoMoreRansom ([link here](https://www.nomoreransom.org)) will help you with `ransomware` identification and relevant decryption steps. Here are all of their decryption tools: https://www.nomoreransom.org/en/decryption-tools.html

If you are sure that it is the `Dharma ransomware` then they have the steps to decryption listed here for that particular infection: https://www.nomoreransom.org/uploads/RakhniDecryptor_how-to_guide.pdf